# Drag and Drop angular2 Dragula

Tags: typescript, angular, drag-and-drop, dragula

I'm using ng2-dragula to drag and drop elements.
I need that my drag&drop be in one direction

for example I have a menu of items and I fill my div with this items so its not logical to drag from my div to menu.

I had already found this config to keep my items in menu

```
 this.dragulaService.setOptions('first-bag', {
            copy: true,
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an 'id' to your menu and change your setOptions as follow:

```
this.dragulaService.setOptions('first-bag', {
  accepts: function (el, target, source, sibling) {
    return (target.id != 'dragula-source');
  },
  copy: true
});
```